# when i using simple query this is working fine but when binding the data through gridview this is not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

```
SELECT
    CAST(date AS DATE),
    SUM(amt) AS totamt
FROM TableName
GROUP BY CAST(date AS DATE)
```

when I using simple query this is working fine but when binding the data through gridview this is not working and throws the error:

> DataBinding:'System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal' does not contain a property with the name 'ExpenseDate'.

Comment: binding to a gridview.. what is this ? asp.NET ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not selecting `ExpenseDate` from database and trying to bind that column into your gridview. You should edit your database query to select `ExpenseDate` and then bind that in front end or remove that binding from front end.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should rename the date column as expected by your gridview

```
SELECT 
CAST(date AS DATE) as ExpenseDate, 
SUM(amt) AS totamt 
FROM TableName 
GROUP BY CAST(date AS DATE)
```